# Create Trigger With If Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

My problem is this:

> Create a trigger named Products_UPDATE that checks the new value for
> the DiscountPercent column of the Products table. This trigger should
> raise an appropriate error if the discount percent is greater than 100
> or less than 0.
>
> If the new discount percent is between 0 and 1, this trigger should
> modify the new discount percent by multiplying it by 100. That way, a
> discount percent of .2 becomes 20.
>
> Test this trigger with an appropriate UPDATE statement.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Products_UPDATE
ON Products
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN 
IF (SELECT Products.DiscountPercent FROM Products 
JOIN inserted ON Products.DiscountPercent = inserted.DiscountPercent) > 100 OR (SELECT Products.DiscountPercent FROM Products 
JOIN inserted ON Products.DiscountPercent = inserted.DiscountPercent) < 0
RAISERROR(N'Percent has to be between 0 and 100',16,1)
END
BEGIN
IF
(SELECT Products.DiscountPercent FROM Products 
JOIN inserted ON Products.DiscountPercent = inserted.DiscountPercent) > 0 AND (SELECT Products.DiscountPercent FROM Products 
JOIN inserted ON Products.DiscountPercent = inserted.DiscountPercent) < 1
UPDATE Products
SET DiscountPercent = DiscountPercent * 100
WHERE DiscountPercent = (SELECT Products.DiscountPercent FROM Products 
JOIN inserted ON Products.DiscountPercent = inserted.DiscountPercent)
END
GO
UPDATE Products
SET DiscountPercent = 103
WHERE ProductID = 1;
```

So it isn't throwing an error when I update the `DiscountPercent` greater than 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what your joins were trying to accomplish. You should be able to carry out your check and insert entirely using the `Inserted` pseudo-table. You don't need a second check for the update as the `raiserror` will not allow the rest of the trigger to continue.

You can use a `case` expression to compute the discount.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Products_UPDATE
ON Products
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN 
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Inserted I
    WHERE I.DiscountPercent > 100 OR I.DiscountPercent < 0
    ) BEGIN
    -- Should be using throw
    RAISERROR(N'Percent has to be between 0 and 100',16,1);
  END;

  UPDATE Products SET
    DiscountPercent = DiscountPercent * 100
  WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM Inserted)
  AND DiscountPercent < 1;
END;
GO
```

Note: You should really be using `throw` rather than `raiserror` now.

Comment: Far better to move the check on DiscountPercent to the where clause in the update statement to avoid pointlessly multiplying the column by 1 (which will again cause the update trigger to run)